# How to properly return defered object in iced coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

I'm trying to do async/await style of programming using coffeescript and iced coffeescript.

What I get instead if 'undefined' response.

```
module.exports = update: (req, res) ->
    await user = User.find({ id: 1 }).exec (err, user) ->
        throw err if err?

        console.log(err) # null
        console.log(user) # object

        defer user

    console.log user # undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will not work because the iced-coffeescript syntax for `await, defer` is used slightly differently. See [#iced](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/#iced)

You have put `defer` into the `await` code block, but it is actually used a as callback for `await`.

Edit: Callback function was missing.

```
module.exports = update: (req, res) ->

  findUser = (id, cb) ->
    await user = User.find({ id: 1 }), defer err, user
    if err then return [ err, null ]
    cb err, user

  await findUser id, defer result

  console.log result.user
```

Comment: With this example `console.log user` never executes